# How to print an object in a ListView

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to print a ListView with Android Studio. I succeeded in printing one string in every element of the list, but now I would like to print an object called User that contains two strings (a username and a radio name).

Here is my main activity:

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

//Variables
private User User1 = new User("User1","Radio1");
private User User2 = new User("User2","Radio2");
private User User3 = new User("User3","Radio3");
private User[] mUsers = {User1, User2, User3};

//GUI Widgets
ListView mListUsers = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    //Bind GUI Widgets
    mListUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.users_list, mUsers.getName()); //The getName() is not found here
    mListUsers.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    mListUsers.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

My main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/usersListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:paddingBottom="3dip" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

users_list.xml :

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:paddingTop="4dip"
android:paddingBottom="3dip"
android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Could you give me any tips please?

Comment: You are giving the adapter its data-source, when you use the constructor `new ArrayAdapter<>()`. It needs an array as its parameter, which is your `mUsers`. So depending on what you plan to do with your adapter you probably need to loop through the array in the adapter itself and there get the things you want to print. `mUsers` itself is an array which contains several Users. So the array has no `getName()`, only the Users themselves have that method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I agree that mUsers.getName() is not an array. I tried declaring my ArrayAdapter with <User> instead of <String> but that didn't work of course... I'm getting a bit confused here, what do you mean by "loop throughthe array in the adapter itself"?

Comment: A `ArrayAdapter` usually gets an array and simply displays the contents by using the `toString()`. Therefore you could override the `toString()` in your `User`-class to read what you want. Or else you need to write your own adapter-class and implement the `getView()`. See: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: Oh yeah, now I see the idea, thanks a lot !